# What is the best approach when creating a custom angular material theme?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm trying to understand how to best work with Angular-material theming:

Google's giving out a wide range of [color palettes](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette),
And also provides guides on how to [easily switch between palettes](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.0/demo/colors).

I've seen this [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/37520), And found a bunch of tools to generate a palette around a main color ([tool1](http://knizia.biz/mcg/#/), [tool2](http://www.color-hex.com/color/ff0000))

Although when getting a custom design from a designer, where different colors were picked, I find it difficult to implement design colors as a complete theme, **as there are too many variables to take into account** (such as hover shades, ink-ripple shades etc.).

My question is:

1. Can I as a developer create a well enough eye pleasing theme from
       every design that is delivered to me (either by JS theming, or CSS
       overrides), or are there any restrictions to take into account?
2. Should the designer take some guidelines into account when
   creating the design?
3. Should we give away flexibility in design by going with one of
   Google's pre-defined palettes?

**

**Edit - 05/2017:**

I've decided to completely turn off theming since I couldn't fully understand how to customize it to our needs.

Im now injecting variables through webpack into SASS files and the outcode is much more sane.

**

Comment: I was just finding a best example of Angular Material to start with my new application and I found this:
http://fuse-angular-material.withinpixels.com/dashboard-project.
After that, I developed a new application from scratch after using this theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, not currently. "Well-pleasing" is a broad, opinion-based term that is not decided by logical algorithm. I actually have tried to do exactly this for months before I finally learned enough about UI design to know it wouldn't work.
2. Google's material design guideline is all that's needed for a designer to create a Material Theme. It's not that long and a typical designer can skim through it in about an hour.
3. No. Google's pre-defined palettes are meant to be used by programmers to quickly create sites with acceptable interface. Unless you work specifically for Google, there's no reason to limit the designer's palette. They are totally fine as guidelines, though. See [Dark Material UI](https://www.behance.net/gallery/31230911/Dark-Material-UI-Design), a design concept based on Material Design but doesn't adhere to many part of the guidelines (for example it uses colors not included in Google's color palettes)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you tell me if you customize your theme via $mdThemingProvider or SASS variables ?

Comment: I uses SASS mostly when I want to create an entirely new theme (since it takes quite some time), $mdThemingProvider I use when I just want to extend a theme and change some parts.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that we use is simply changing the href of css file in your html head section. In this case you have standalone css file for every theme, and when you need to switch, you simply modify href.

No need to use additional markup as google recommends, because it will be to complicated to switch between themes, especially if there lots of themes.

You can look at an example here:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/how-to/change-themes-on-the-client

There is a live example available. And material theme as well.

Comment: I can't see how this answers my question?